# Converting string to currency value

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL. I have column with values of `String` type, that actually supposed to be a currency.

The strings values are in the following format:

```
103,2 %
```

I need to convert it to:

```
103.2
```

Aldo i need to convert the values type to `Float`.

Is there's a good conversation functions that can help me? Do i need to do that with `Replace()` function?

Comment: Is `%` a literal character, or are you using it as a wildcard for any currency symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
select cast(translate(col, ', %', '.') as float)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it would be enough for that moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` to strip out the fixed `%` part, which changed `103,2 %` to `103,2`; and pass the result of that into `to_number()`. Since you seem to have a comma decimal separtator in the value and period in the databse you can specify the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS:

```
select to_number(replace('103,2 %', ' %'),
  '999999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''') as value
from dual;

     VALUE
----------
     103.2
```

If you don't have quite a fixed format - the space may or not be there, for example, or you could have different currency symbols instead of % - then you could use `translate` as Gordon Linoff showed, or use a regular expression to remove any non-numeric characters:

```
select to_number(regexp_replace('103,2 %', '[^[:digit:],]'),
  '999999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''') as value
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert character strings to numeric values by using the `CAST(string AS DECIMAL)` or `CAST(string AS SIGNED INTEGER)`

Comment: The space and `%` (whether that is literal or supposed to be a wildcard) would make the cast fail with ORA-01722; and the OP wants the answer as a float, not an integer.